# I am not able to pass variables from a dynamic list to a php page for processing. Is this a logic issue that I am not understanding?

Tags: javascript, php

I am very new to PHP and am just an knitter of javascript at this point. I am creating a call log where the users are entering information regarding call they receive. The reason and issue fields need to be dynamic is because of the amount of information that needs to be processed regarding the types of calls that are being received and having the ability to create meaningful reports later with that information. I am able to pass all other variables on the agentcall.php page except the call Issue and call Reason fields which are dynamic so that the issue is selected and then only the choices for that reason are displayed. I want those values passed from agentcall.php to agentprocess.php to be posted to the database. But right now, if I can just get them to echo that would be a start and maybe I can figure out what else I might need to do. I have included snippets of code that I think would help with helping with this issue and figuring out what I am missing.

agentcall.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {

                $("#issue").change(function() {

                var $dropdown = $(this);

                $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {

                    var key = $dropdown.val();
                    var vals = [];

                    switch(key) {
                        case 'agent':
                            vals = data.agent.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'compliance':
                            vals = data.compliance.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'equipment':
                            vals = data.equipment.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'system':
                            vals = data.system.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'transfer':
                            vals = data.transfer.split(",");
                            break;
                        case 'disconnect':
                            vals = data.disconnect.split(",");
                            break;  
                        case 'complaints':
                            vals = data.compliants.split(",");
                            break;      
                        case 'base':
                            vals = ['Please choose an option'];
                    }

                    var $reason = $("#reason");
                    $reason.empty();
                    $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                        $reason.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");

                    });

                });
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
Issue Code&nbsp;<select id="issue">
            <option value="base">Please select an option</option>
            <option value="agent">Agent</option>
            <option value="compliance">Compliance</option>
            <option value="equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="system">System</option>
            <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
            <option value="disconnect">Disconnected or Dropped Call</option>
            <option value="complaints">Complaints</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />          
            Reason Code&nbsp;<select id="reason">
            <option>Please choose an option</option>
            </select>
            <br />      
            <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

agentprocess.php

```
<?php
require conn.php;
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$issue= $_GET['issue'];
$reason= $_GET['reason'];

$issue = stripslashes($issue);
$reason = stripslashes($reason);

$issue = mysqli_real_escape_string($issue);
$reason =  mysqli_real_escape_string($reason);

echo "$issue";
echo "$reason";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer to my own question on a page about how JSON works and so far so go. I am sure that there are other ways to solve this but I found the answer in the JSON side of the code. This is what I added to solve the issue:

$.issue('processpage.php', issue, function(issue){ alert(issue); });
$.reason('processpage.php', issue, function(issue){ alert(issue); });
it carries the value of the variable to the processing page so that it can be inserted into the DB for use.